# need finite xlim values (error in building predictions R)

Tags: r, plot

I am new to R and trying to plot a marginal relationship between an estimated probability of a response and years of education. I used this formula to build for the marginal relationship between an estimated probability of a response and age and it worked fine.

```
m<-300 # number of data points in prediction
age_predict<-min(newdat$age)+ (max(newdat$age)-min(newdat$age))*seq(0,1,1/(m-1))
```

but when I try to change the age variable to the education variable (education.num)

```
education_predict<-min(newdat$education.num)+ (max(newdat$education.num)-min(newdat$education.num))*seq(0,1,1/(m-1))
```

I get the following error code

```
no non-missing arguments to min; returning Infno non-missing arguments to max; returning -Infno non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
```

and my education_predict is full of N/A.

Why is this error code showing up for one variable and not the other? How can I get it to work for education.num?

Comment: I tried this and I am still getting the same error code. I also checked my data set and there are no missing values for any variable. The minimum for education.num is 1 and the maximum is 16

Comment: Are you sure your spelling of `education.num` is consistent betwenen the calls you are showing and the way it is defined in the data frame?  "no non-missing arguments" sounds like it isn't finding the right variable.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you see that error is because `education.num` has missing data (which will show up as `NA` in R).  The "easy" fix is to ignore the NA's, which can be done in both the `min` and `max` formulas:

```
education_predict<-min(newdat$education.num, na.rm = TRUE)+ (max(newdat$education.num, na.rm = TRUE)-min(newdat$education.num, na.rm = TRUE))*seq(0,1,1/(m-1))
```

You do need to be aware that there are missing values being ignored though so you can make sure that they aren't going to impact the analysis.